# How does someone get a job as a community manager or social media person? How do you even define your skills?

Tags: moderators, site-administration

I have been volunteering my time as a Facebook admin for both page and groups (I am a FB power admin), YouTube moderator (particularly for live streams), and for a largeish subreddit (>500k) as a moderator. I'm looking to turn this into a part time stream of income (I work full time already), but I don't know how to define these skills. Is this a community manager? A social media specialist? I wouldn't want to touch Tiktok, I'm pretty much lost with Instagram, and am just an average user on Twitter. How do people go about finding these opportunities and breaking into the field? I've looked on some freelance sights but haven't been able to find anything like what I've described.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the answer on how to find the job or polish your CV, but based on what I've been trying, you do NOT need previous experience with TikTok, Instagram, have 100k followers on Twitter. It helps to have some previous experience, but you don't need it at the time you apply for the job. What you need to do is to show that whatever you do on Facebook or Reddit, including freelance work, is to show results, including some metrics somewhere in your CV.